# Reset autoincrement values in SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

If my SQLite database has 5 rows and 1st column as autoincremented field and then I deleted the 3rd row then how can I update the value of primary key of all rows in a autoincremented form starting from one.

Initial table:

[image]

Table after deletion of row

[image]

but I want something like this:-

[image]

How can I achieve this result using SQLite queries.

Comment: There is no contract which says that an auto increment column has to always follow some sequence pattern.  Rather, the only requirement is that each ID assigned is unique.  You should be using some other column(s) to do what you want here.

Comment: That completely defeats the point and purpose of `AUTOINCREMENT`, which is that each automatically generated rowid is unique over the life the table. See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for details.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing *rowid* (A unique numeric identifier for a row) with *row numbers* (Which can be generated on the fly)...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In sqlite, an automatically generated rowid for an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` column is guaranteed to be larger than the largest one that's been used so far (Even if it is later deleted). Without `AUTOINCREMENT`, they can be randomly generated in certain circumstances (And reused).

Comment: @Shawn Didn't know this...but I'm pretty sure that in some other databases this may not be the case.  Good information +1.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for your suggestion It can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Although the manipulation of Primary Keys is **not recommended** what you want to achieve can be achieved.

Assuming that by saying *"1st column as autoincremented field"* that the pk column is defined with the AUTOINCREMENT keyword rather than just an alias of the rowid (which autoincrements anyway see [SQLite - AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)).

Then you could using SQL such as the following (again **not recommended**):-

```
/* Create and populate the test table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, set_name_fk TEXT, question TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,'A','Question0'),(2,'B','Question1'),(3,'C','Question2'),(4,'D','Question3'),(5,'E','Question4');

/* Do the deletion */
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE question = 'Question2';

/* Start the manipulation */
/* Just in case it exists DROP the temporary table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_othermytable;
/* Create the temporary table to maintain the column definitions */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_othermytable (pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, set_name_fk TEXT, question TEXT);
/* Populate the temporary table manipulating the pk value accordingly */
INSERT INTO new_othermytable SELECT coalesce((SELECT count(pk) FROM mytable WHERE pk < x.pk),0) + 1 AS pk, set_name_fk, question FROM mytable  AS x ORDER BY pk;
/* DROP the original table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
/* Rename the temporary table to be the original table */
ALTER TABLE new_othermytable RENAME TO mytable;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

The crux of the above is the query that selects the count of the rows with a lower pk value than the current row (coalesce sets this to 0 if there are no rows) and then adds 1, thus effectively renumbering the pk i.e. `SELECT coalesce((SELECT count(pk) FROM mytable WHERE pk < x.pk),0) + 1`

The query could be used to get the desired output without having to change the table.